# How to arrange long (time consuming) actions on Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

For instance, we are in SomeActivity and the activity has a button that invokes moving files from one dir to another (let's call it job).

On BlackBerry I would:

1. push a non-cancellable popup (Dialog screen) saying "Please wait..."
2. start a thread that fulfills the job
3. on thread completion close the popup

This approach 99.99% can guarantee that we stay on the same screen after the task is over, user just sees the popup and waits for job completion. Device rotation or whatever does not break the desired workflow.

On Android things change. I know there's the AsyncTask that is probably provided to solve my case. There's even a good [example](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/activity/ShelvesActivity.java) of how it should be used. But since there's no guarantee of how long an Activity instance will live the AsyncTask should be cancelled on onSaveInstanceState (and restarted on onRestoreInstanceState). This means using AsyncTask there's no guarantee we are able to fully fulfill the job once started. In some cases as sending an http post request for creating a user I would not want to get in "user already exists for this login" trouble on reruning the AsyncTask. This is possible since the AsyncTask can be interrupted while the request is already sent (and the server actually is doing its job - creating a new user), but the AsyncTask is canceled before we got the response.

Is there any solution on Android to get the BB-like behaviour stated above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In May 2010 Google issued a new IO session called [Developing Android REST client applications](http://www.google.com/intl/uk-UA/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html) which explains how to achieve exactly what I asked for.

It turned out the question is rather complicated, so there is no easy and quick solution. The solution requires deep knowledge of Android platform/API. This is the price caused by the flexibility of the app process/Activity lifecycles.

I feel some oddity on why this info was not presented from the very first version of Android. Looks like Google knew how to write 100% bugless apps and for some marketing reason did not share the approach. Just imagine how many buggy apps was written by May 2010.

Anyway I'm glad now I have smth we call best practice approach.

Answer (score 2):

> But since there's no guarantee of how
>   long an Activity instance will live
>   the AsyncTask should be cancelled on
>   onSaveInstanceState (and restarted on
>   onRestoreInstanceState).

Or have it be managed by a `Service`.

Comment: I should study this component because I've been already adviced to use it twice.

Comment: Hi, CommonsWare.
Is there a detailed explanation of how the long running jobs should be architectured/coded on Android in any of your books?

Comment: That depends a bit on what you define as "long running jobs". I cover services with AsyncTask in one book (http://commonsware.com/Android) -- see http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/WeatherPlus/ for the project in question. I cover the use of AlarmManager to avoid everlasting services in another book (http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid) -- see http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Alarm/ for that project.

Comment: Saw your responce only now (I thought there would be some sort of email notification on new comment, but there wasn't).

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for proper long running job thread handling under progress popup assuming user invoked it from Activity. The problem is how to "syncronize" a job thread with Activity's life-cycle. That was my original post about.

Comment: So, your first one (service with AsyncTask in WeatherPlus) is of interest. Cool. As I got it the service will do its AsyncTask to the very end (the AsyncTask's doInBackground() will not be interrupted unless the whole app process is killed by OS). Thus device rotations will not cause the AsyncTask interruption. After the AsyncTask has finished - an Intent broadcast is being sent. Activity can handle the broadcast only being active (between onResume() and onPause()).

Comment: Sorry for probably silly questions:
What will happen if at the time the broadcast is being sent the Activity has already been killed by OS (because of RAM shortage). Will the broadcast "wake up" the Activity to handle the broadcast?

Comment: No, the broadcast will simply be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the response, CommonsWare.

I'm looking for the best class to be a dispatcher for AsyncTasks invoked from my Activities. It could be one of these:
1. subclass of Application;
2. subclass of Service;
3. my own static stuff (a class an instance of which can not be created).

As for me it's simlier to implement the 3rd choice. But the question is will it be more death-resistant than Service or Application? Also it's interesting what will live longer - Application or Service?

Answer (score 1):

If your Activity wants to stay on the screen, you can simply start a Thread like this:

```
final File fromFile = ...;
final File toFile = ...;

new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // do something with fromFile, toFile
    }
}.start();
```

That way the GUI-Thread is ready to do other thinks like displaying a

```
  android.app.ProgressDialog
```

Also, consider making the Dialog uncancellable with

```
  ProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

That way the user can only leave via the HOME-Key, which you get notified of when

```
  Activity.onPause()
```

is called. Futhermore you might want to look into Wakelocks, to stop the Screen from turning black and your application pushed in the background where it might be killed. You'd do this in the Thread:

```
  PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ivContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
  Wakelock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, "MyApp");
  wakeLock.acquire();

  // ... copy stuff ...

  wakeLock.release();
```

Of course you'd have to release the wakeLock, too, when the user leaves via the HOME-Key.

Finally if you want to call GUI-Elements from your background-thread, this will only work if the Thread is part of the GUI-Event-Loop, like the normal Thread is you are running in, when getting called with on...-Methods. To achieve this your background-thread will have to callback to the GUI-Thread via a Handler. Like this:

```
  private Handler mHandler = new Handler() { 
      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          Log.v(TAG, "Got Message "+msg.what); // prints: Got Message 77
      // ... do GUI actions ...
      }    
  };

  // ... in Thread ...

  int lvInfo = 77;
  mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(lvInfo);
```

You can even put objects in the message like so:

```
  Message txtMsg = Message.obtain();
  textMsg.obj = "Hello World";
  mHandler.sendMessage(lvTextMsg);
```

Comment: rflexor, thanks for your answer. Specifically for a Wakelocks point.