# Handle screen orientation changes when there are AsyncTasks running

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've been bugged by this for a while. How do I properly handle screen orientation changes while I have a separate `Thread` / `AsyncTask` running? Currently, I have

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

in my `AndroidManifest.xml`, but that is [not really encouraged](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config):

> **Note:** Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last-resort. Please read Handling Runtime Changes for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.

Also, in the **2.3 emulator**, it works when switching to `landscape`, but switching back to `portrait` fails.

Now, the reason why I use `configChanges` is because when the user switches orientation, I might have an `AsyncTask` running, doing some network traffic, and I don't want it stopped.

Is there any other way of doing this, or is there a way of fixing 2.3 to switch back to portrait?

I know about `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`, but I'm not sure it would be a good idea to "save" the `AsyncTask` instance, mainly because the class that extends `AsyncTask` is not static (so it is tied to the `Activity`) -- and it needs to be, because in `onPostExecute()` it calls methods from the `Activity` instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem to your and worked around it by implementing the `AsyncTask` as part of a class which inherits from [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class. An `Application` class is available all the life time of the application So you don't have to worry about your `AsyncTask` getting interrupted unless the whole application will be killed.

To get notified when the task has finished the `Activity` has to implement a interface which it uses to register itself to the `Application` class.

When your application is destroyed because of the screen rotation you can unregister your `Activity` from the `Application` class and re-register it when it is recreated. If the task finishes between destruction and recreation the result of the operation can be stored in the `Application` class meanwhile so the `Activity` can check whether the task is still running or whether the result is already available when it is recreated.

Another advantage is that you have direct access to the applications context because the `Application` class is a sub class of the `Context` class.

Comment: Very nice, much simpler than implementing a `Service`. Thanks.

Comment: @Flo I know this has been a while since the post but I am trying to do the same but I don't quite understand what you mean by "To get notified when the task has finished the Activity has to implement a interface which it uses to register itself to the Application class." Any chance of an example? (I'm new to java and android1)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a code example. But have a look at [the observer pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483644/rosetta-stone-observer-pattern) I hope you will then understand what I mean with "register" (update()) and "notify" (addObserver()).

Comment: Ah in my former comment I mixed something up. "Register" would mean calling the addObserver() method and "notifying" would mean calling update().

Answer (score 2):

Take a look the droid-fu library `BetterAsyncTask`. It is meant to handle this exact case.

http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/16/introducing-droid-fu-for-android-betteractivity-betterservice-and-betterasynctask/

Answer (score 0):

I already popped up similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241049/how-to-arrange-long-time-consuming-actions-on-android).

Basically there is an [example](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/activity/ShelvesActivity.java) of how to pause/resume an `AsynTask` on device rotation. However it still does not fit for all cases (sometimes it is not possible to safely suspend the action, such as a new user creation on a remote server). For those "unsafe" cases you need to code somewhat I'd call a tricky "framework". You will see CommonsWare gives github links to the one.

Comment: So there's no way (easy) to keep the `AsyncTask` running while the `Activity` is being restarted. Bummer. However, I found out the not-switching-back-to-portrait is an emulator problem, since the settings app does the same thing.