# Handling screen orientation changes in Android -- am I doing it right?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I found out that Android destroys and recreates activities during screen orientation changes. I have an Activity that automatically looks up the device's nominal location and displays it back to the user. This location is stored in a record-keeping object that is used throughout the course of the application. Here's my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location);

    currentLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCurrentLocation);
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
        new LocationDetectionTask(this).execute((Void[]) null);
    else
        currentLocation.setText(record.getLocation());

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
}
```

(As you might be able to tell, `record` represents that data record object).

Is this method of handling screen orientation changes sufficient? By the way, I am not overriding `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`.

Also, a side question: since `LocationDetectionTask` is an `AsyncTask`, how do I go about handling screen orientation changes for that?

Edit: I forgot to clarify this. After the `LocationDetectionTask` finds the location, it puts it in the `record`.

Comment: As a side comment.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584015/handle-screen-orientation-changes-when-there-are-asynctasks-running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) to save your information as this will get called before the activity destroys itself on orientation change. I would try to use onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) when getting the information back, but it should work on the onCreate() method too. (An example here [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state))

Keep in mind that the Bundle should be used to save primitive types. If you want to pass a more complex object, you can try to pass a Parcelable object. (More info here http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html)