# Calling multiple functions with Asynctask for network connection

Tags: android, android-asynctask

II want to build a class that every time I want to do a network connection, I'll use it.
I want to open a dialog first and then make the network connection (or get something from SQL or download something from the web or update the SQL) and then close the dialog.

I need to wait for the function to end before I can continue.

I wanted to use `AsyncTask`, but I can't figure out a way to determine in the `AsyncTask` which function to use. I found two solutions, `switch-case` or trying to send a function with java reflection. Both solutions are not too good.

Does someone have another idea or another way to do this?

Comment: Praise the lord that someone wants to do the same thing as me. I really hope you get some answers. I want to have a class that I can reuse my network function as well, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to display the loading dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the `Command` design pattern.
[Here is Java example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-command). You can extend it by callbacks to do something after finishing background work.

```
public abstract class Command {

    protected AsyncTaskCallback callback;

    public Command(AsyncTaskCallback callback) {
            this.callback = callback;
    }

    public abstract void execute();

    public AsyncTaskCallback getCallback() {
        return callback;
    }

    public interface AsyncTaskCallback {
        public void onPreExecute();
        public void onPostExecute();
    }

}
```

Invoker:

```
public class Invoker extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private Command command;

    public static void execute(Command command) {
            new Invoker(command).execute();
    }

    private Invoker(Command command) {
            this.command = command;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return command.execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
            if (command.getCallback() != null) {
                    command.getCallback().onPreExecute();
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (command.getCallback() != null) {
                    command.getCallback().onPostExecute();
            }
    }
```

}

So, your AsyncTask doesn't know which command it is executing and thus can be used throughout the app. Now you can implement interface `AsyncTaskCallback` in your `Activity` and handle there all UI-related things you need.

Example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements AsyncTaskCallback {

...

public void onPreExecute() {
    showProgress();
}

public void onPostExecute() {
    hideProgress();
    doOtherThings();
}

...

Command myCommand = new Command(this) {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        // Do specific background work
    }
}
Invoker.execute(command);
```

Also you need to handle [orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128670/best-practice-asynctask-during-orientation-change).

Answer (score 2):

The Android docs have good examples of how to use `AsyncTask`.  [There's one here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  If you want to add some code to show dialogs, then maybe something like this:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

     // Constant for identifying the dialog
     private static final int LOADING_DIALOG = 1000;
     private Activity parent;

     public DownloadFilesTask(Activity parent) {
         // record the calling activity, to use in showing/hiding dialogs
         this.parent = parent;
     }

     protected void onPreExecute () {
         // called on UI thread
         parent.showDialog(LOADING_DIALOG); 
     }

     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         // called on the background thread
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         // called on the UI thread
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         // this method is called back on the UI thread, so it's safe to 
         //  make UI calls (like dismissing a dialog) here
         parent.dismissDialog(LOADING_DIALOG);
     }
 }
```

Before performing the background work, `onPreExecute()` will be called back.  This is an *optional* method to override in your `AsyncTask` subclass, but it gives you a chance to throw up a UI before the network/database work starts.

After the background work completes, you have another opportunity to update the UI (or remove a dialog) in `onPostExecute()`.

You'd use this class (from within an `Activity`) like so:

```
DownloadFilesTask task = new DownloadFilesTask(this);
task.execute(new URL[] { new URL("http://host1.com/file.pdf"), 
                         new URL("http://host2.net/music.mp3") });
```

Comment: Here's where personally this doesn't work for me (not sure about OP) but the line that is right after `task.execute` will start executing immediately afterwards while the tasks `doInBackground` is running. How can I hold off on it executing until it's 100% done? I just want to have the progressDialog up.

Comment: @unexpected62, If you want something to run **after** the task completes, then you put it inside the `onPostExecute()` method.  Or at least, *trigger* it from within that method.

Comment: Gah - that's what I keep reading, but I feel like I'd put the rest of my app in `onPostExecute`. I must be missing a design principal here.

Comment: @unexpected62, Can you tell me what you're doing *after* the task?  Is it just a UI operation?  Is it another download?  Something else?  I can be more helpful if you're specific about what comes *after* this task.

Comment: @unexpected62 You can pass a callback to your AsyncTask subclass, and then call it in the onPostExecute(). or I think If I get you right just not to use AsyncTask, because you dont want async behaviour