# Android UI Thread Message Queue dispatch order

Tags: android, android-asynctask

While working with retain Fragments in Android to hold an AsyncTask during configuration changes, which i guess it's the best approach, some doubts appear in my mind about UI Thread's Message Queue invocation order.

Ex: 
Imagine this scenario:

1. Configuration Change occurs, user rotates the device. AsyncTask is running.
2. Fragment `onDetach()` is called
3. AsyncTask `doInBackground()` method finishes
4. AsyncTask `onPostExecute()`is called
5. Fragment `onAttach()` is called

So can UI Thread Message Queue be like this:

> Queue top -> onDetach() | onPostExecute() | onAttach()

I know it cannot, the call to `onPostExecute()` will wait until the configuration change completes,  as far as i know, but how does that work ? Are the calls from Activities, Fragments life-cycles executed consecutively ?

Comment: Yes, since `onPostExecute()` runs un the UI thread, it would be executed consecutively with the UI and configuration changes, which also run on the UI thread. My assumption is that `onDetach()` and `onAttach()` run somewhat atomically, as the ActivityManager probably doesn't yield to other threads during configuration changes, but that's something you'd have to dig into Android source to confirm.

Comment: yeah looking in android source code is probably the best way to find out, how it works.

Comment: @323go To clarify further, Android never has to "yield to other threads" in this case. Atomicity is guaranteed by the single-threaded nature of the Android UI toolkit (i.e. events are executed sequentially in a single, centralized message queue).

Answer (score 119, accepted):

It is not possible for `onPostExecute()` to be called in between `Fragment#onDetach()` and `Fragment#onAttach()` during a configuration change. The reasoning behind this claim is threefold:

1. Configuration changes are handled inside a single message in the main thread's message queue.
2. As soon as the `doInBackground()` method returns, the `AsyncTask` schedules the `onPostExecute()` method to be invoked on the main thread by posting a message to the main thread's message queue.
3. The configuration change's message will contain the code that will invoke the `Activity` and `Fragment` lifecycle methods (such as `onDetach()` and `onAttach()`). The `AsyncTask`'s message will contain the code that will invoke the `onPostExecute()` method. Since the main thread processes messages in its message queue sequentially, it is impossible for the two messages to be executed at the same time, and therefore `onPostExecute()` can never be invoked in between the calls to `onDetach()` and `onAttach()`.

Read my response to Doug Stevenson in [this thread](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AlexLockwood/posts/etWuiiRiqLf) for a more detailed explanation (including links to the source code that prove the claim).

Comment: during a configuration change, is it guaranteed that `onAttach` is posted to the message queue right after `onDetach`?

Comment: @DavidT. Both `onDetach` and `onAttach` are invoked inside the same message by the main UI thread.

Comment: Isn't this just a current implementation detail and thus we'd be relying on white box behavior? E.g. couldn't this behavior change in the future?

Comment: @greg7gkb You might be right about that... I feel like I remember reading that this was intentional behavior that won't break in the future from some of the Android guys, but I forget where this is documented.

Comment: I see some flaws in your proposed solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53603796/ui-updates-across-config-changes-the-weird-point

Comment: Google+ RIP, is there mirror for "response to Doug Stevenson" link?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple test to see the lifecycle about the `AsyncTask` in a retained `Fragment`.
It can confirm that @Alex Lockwood's answer is true.
So it's safe to say the `AsyncTask` in a retained `Fragment` is the best practice. And Google should put this approach into their official documents.

```
public class RecordDataFragment extends Fragment {
    public static boolean detach = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Timber.d("retain, onAttach");
        detach = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        Timber.d("retain, onDetach");
        detach = true;
    }

    public static class TestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(String... username) {

            Timber.d("retain, looping.");

            while(!detach){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Timber.d("retain, exit looping.");

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void nothing) {
            Timber.d("retain, onPostExecute");
        }
    }
}

public class RecordFragment extends Fragment {

    static boolean called = false;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Timber.d("retain, onResume");

        if(!called) {
            new RecordDataFragment.TestTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
            called = true;
        }

    }
}

2019-11-22 12:28:55.503 D/RecordDataFragment: retain, onAttach
2019-11-22 12:32:00.263 D/RecordFragment: retain, onViewStateRestored
2019-11-22 12:32:03.538 D/RecordFragment: retain, onResume
2019-11-22 12:32:03.544 D/RecordDataFragment$TestTask: retain, looping.
2019-11-22 12:32:07.273 D/RecordDataFragment: retain, onDetach
2019-11-22 12:32:07.297 D/RecordDataFragment$TestTask: retain, exit looping.
2019-11-22 12:32:07.403 D/RecordFragment: retain, onDestroy
2019-11-22 12:32:07.566 D/RecordDataFragment: retain, onAttach
2019-11-22 12:32:08.621 D/RecordFragment: retain, onViewStateRestored
2019-11-22 12:32:08.870 D/RecordFragment: retain, onResume
2019-11-22 12:32:09.663 D/RecordDataFragment$TestTask: retain, onPostExecute
```