# UI updates across config changes: The weird point

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-configchanges

I am an experienced Android developer and it is a shame that I am still ineffectively fighting against fundamental issues like persisting UI changes across configuration changes.

I know, this is an all too well known problem and there exists a lot of literature on it. The recommended solution is to `setRetainInstance(true)` a UI-less fragment:

https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

[Best practice: AsyncTask during orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128670/best-practice-asynctask-during-orientation-change)

For the sake of completeness, let me draw up the scenario. You have an `AsyncTask` that performs a Network request and is supposed to update the UI in `onPostExecute()`

I see some issues with the proposed solution:

- The proposed solution says that `onPostExecute()` is guaranteed to not be called during between the calls to `onDetach()` and the next `onAttach()` but what if the AsyncTask returns early(after Activity's `onPause()` and before the call to `onDetach()`). If `onPostExecute()` executes during the period, since `onSaveInstanceState()` will have been called, any update to the Views will not persist across Activity restart.
- Second if the `AsyncTask` returns such that `onPostExecute()` executes before the call to Activity's `onCreate()` then the views will not have been initialized for any view updates to be pushed yet.

Is there any effective solution against this problem that addresses memory leaks and state save across config changes?

Comment: Have you taken a look to ViewModel  and LiveData architecture components? That's the best way nowadays to deal with configuration changes. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel and https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: @dglozano : I have but not everyone would be onboard with these solution in our team and there is legacy code to maintain

Comment: Using lifecycle aware components is also not an option for your team? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle

Comment: @alex-lockwood : Do you think I have missed up on anything in your blog post?