# Android - Asynctask re-run when rotating devive

Tags: android

In my asynctask, my app shows a progress bar and imageview from URL. It's good. But when I rotate my device, Asynctask rerun (Progress bar show and image loaded again). I don't want it loaded again, I just want them rotate follow my device.
How to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Refer to [Similar Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128670/best-practice-asynctask-during-orientation-change)

Comment: I second @hypd09's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you have to use [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html). More information about loaders you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) and [toturial here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html)

Other way to do async tasks is use Services. I prefer to use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) with [ResultReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html). It implement Parcelable interface, you can easily pass it to IntentService with intent and then pass back information to your activity through Handler.

Comment: When someone mixes two concepts or mechanisms in such a way, it may be the sign that they don't have a clear understanding of neither. `Service`s are designed to be used for background operations that you want the application to perform even if the user is not interacting with any of the application's activities, or no application's activity is currently executing on the device. The _raison d'etre_ of `AsyncTask`s is to perform operations where results need to be used to update the UI of an application's activity. Quite different purposes, aren't they.

Comment: Absolutely disagree. AsyncTasks is outdated and should not used for now at all, because it contains a lot of design problems, e.g. author's issue. That's why loaders were done. IntentService is **"work queue processor"** as documentation said, so it very good tool for execute async tasks.

Comment: Except that I didn't question your suggestion of using `AsyncTaskLoader`. I questioned your suggestion to use `Service`s. Please read carefully before commenting.

Comment: The second part you added after I commented the first part? Yeah, right now. I still stand by my suggestion of avoid `Service`s in this case, because their purpose is different from `AsyncTask`s's.

Comment: Yep, after 3 seconds after first part. 'IndentService' is very different from common 'servies', because in works not in main thread.

Comment: So what? Common wisdom suggests to use a `Thread` or similar to perform operations when implementing a plain `Service`. `IntentService` is just a facility over plain `Service`s, so that you don't have to do the multithread lifting yourself. However, `IntentService` is still a `Service`, and still serves a purpose different than `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Fragment` then use `setRetainInstance(true);` inside `onCreate()`

```
// Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
    setRetainInstance(true);
```

This will take care `retaining-objects-across-config-changes`

**For full details** [Handling Configuration Changes with Fragments](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -2):

Add the following line to your activity in the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

This will prevent the `Activity` to recreate and re-run the `ASyncTask`

Comment: It is not good practice for this situation. E.g. changing of system language will cause configChange too. [Look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128670/best-practice-asynctask-during-orientation-change?lq=1) at this answer