# How can I retain an instance of fragment in Android?

Tags: android

I made a fragment and I am showing a `progressDialog`.  When the orientation changes my progress dialog doesn't show again, while I am using a `setRetainInstance(true)`.

Code is

```
public class FragmentTest  extends Fragment implements OnClickListener
 {

Button proceed;
ProgressDialog pDialog;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    if(pDialog!=null)
    {
    pDialog.show();
    }

}

class inner extends AsyncTask
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setMax(900000000);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) 
    {
        int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<10000000;i++)
        {
            pDialog.incrementProgressBy(i);
            for(int j=0;j<10000;j++)
            {
                k=k+j;

            }
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        System.out.println("enter here");
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }



}



@Override
public void onStop() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    if (pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing()){
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

}

But my progress dialog is not showing. Can any one tell me how to solve the problem?

Comment: your pDialog is null since it is instantiated inside the asynctask that you don not `executed`. I can't figured out why you are expecting differently

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7128670/2382964

Comment: now what can i do to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the instance of `ProgressDialog` before you show.

Best approach is to create a method  `showProgress`

```
private void showProgress(){
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    pDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.setMax(900000000);
    pDialog.show();
}
```

And call it when ever required to show the progress dialog.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    showProgress();
}
```