# Android - Retain objects in UI Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

In my project, I originally use this scheme:

> Activity `A` (UI) > Fragment `B` (non-UI) > Adapter + AsyncTask

- `B` retained with `setRetainInstance(true)` and updating `A` UI
- `A` instantiate `B` with `getFragmentManager()`

---

But I now need to use UI Fragments, so I thought to use this scheme:

> Activity `A` > Fragment `B` (UI) > Fragment `C` (non-UI) > Adapter + AsyncTask

- `C` retained with `setRetainInstance(true)` and updating `B` UI
- `B` instantiate `C` with `getChildFragmentManager()`

But it seems not possible:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
    Can't retain fragements that are nested in other fragments
```

I tried to instantiate `C` with `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getChildFragmentManager()` but I had some problems.

---

What is the best practice to retain objects and manage AsyncTasks in a Fragment?

Comment: what about making activity A the owner of both B and C?

Comment: I think it will work but `C` instance manage `B` UI so I would like to nest `C` in `B` or learn the "best practice" - maybe it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally develop a little helper class:

```
public class RetainFragment<F extends Fragment> extends Fragment {

    private static <F extends Fragment> String tag(F ui, Object id) {
        return ui.getClass().getName() + id.toString();
    }

    public static <F extends Fragment> Fragment get(F ui, Object id) {
        return ui.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag(ui, id));
    }

    public F ui;
    public Object id;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public void link(F ui, Object id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.ui = ui;
        if (get(ui, id) == null) {
            ui.getFragmentManager()
              .beginTransaction()
              .add(this, tag(ui, id))
              .commit();
        }
    }

    public void unlink() {
        if (get(ui, id) != null) {
            ui.getFragmentManager()
              .beginTransaction()
              .remove(this)
              .commit();
        }
        ui = null;
        id = null;
    }

}
```

And now, in UI Fragments, I only write:

```
public class UiFragment extends Fragment {

    private static class Retain extends RetainFragment<UiFragment> {
        private MyAsyncTask task;   // Objects to retain over
        private MyAdapter adapter;  // configuration changes
    }

    private Retain retain;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        retain = (Retain) Retain.get(this, 0);
        if (retain == null) {
            retain = new Retain();
            // Retained objects initialization
            retain.adapter = new MyAdapter();
        }
        retain.link(this, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        if (isRemoving()) {
            // Retained objects terminate
            if (retain.task != null) {
                retain.task.cancel(true);
            }
            retain.unlink();
        }
        super.onDetach();
    }

    private void update() {
        if (!isDetached()) {
            // Update UI fragment
        }
    }

}
```

And in `retain.task.onPostExecute()`:

```
retain.ui.update(); // Reference to the last ui fragment instance linked
```

And to launch the task at UI fragment startup:

```
private static class Retain extends RetainFragment<UiFragment> {
    private MyAsyncTask task;   // Objects to retain over
    private MyAdapter adapter;  // configuration changes

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        ui.onRetainCreated();
    }
}

private void onRetainCreated() {
    retain.task = new MyAsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            retain.ui.update();
        }
    };
    retain.task.execute();
}
```