# "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" when fragment is replaced

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my project context, I have a Button `b` in a Fragment `f(1)` in an Activity `a`.

Fragment `f(x)` is an instance of `F` where content depends of argument `x`

I need to replace the current instance `f(1)` by an instance `f(2)` on `b` click event:

- From Activity `a`:

  ```
  private void setFragment(int x) {
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putInt("x", x);
      F f = new F();
      f.setArguments(args);
      f.setListener(new F.Listener() {
          public void onButtonClick(int x) {
              setFragment(x);
          }
      });
      getSupportFragmentManager()
          .beginTransaction()
          .replace(ID, f)
          .commit();
  }
  ```
- From Fragment `f`:

  ```
  b.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {
          listener.onButtonClick(x + 1);
      }
  });
  ```

My problem is:

An Exception is throw on `b` click event **only if a configuration state change occurs**:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Please, what is my error? I read many posts on this Exception but I don't found any solution

---

Edit: I just make a test without AsyncTask, see the code:

Try to rotate the screen and push the button

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (state == null) {
            setFragment(1);
        }
    }

    private void setFragment(int id) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("id", id);
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        myFragment.setArguments(args);
        myFragment.setListener(new MyFragment.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(int id) {
                setFragment(id);
            }
        });
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment, myFragment)
            .commit();
    }

    public static class MyFragment extends Fragment{

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup view, Bundle state) {
            return new Button(getActivity()) {
                {
                    setText(String.valueOf(getArguments().getInt("id")));
                    setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            listener.onClick(getArguments().getInt("id") + 1);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }

        private static interface Listener {
            public void onClick(int id);
        }

        private Listener listener;

        public void setListener(Listener listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: did you come by this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575921/illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate-h, answer says you have to use `transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();` instead of `transaction.commit();`

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry I changed my post, I said big ***. Yes, I tried it but it does not works

Comment: I would suggest changing your approach to replace the fragment from a button that is part of activity rather then the fragment itself. You can try to place it under the current fragment.

Comment: Also this bit.  @Override
            public void onClick(int id) {
                setFragment(id);
            }. You can calling parent activity setFragment(). On orientation change your parent will be destroyed and recreated. You would still be trying to work on old reference (a possible leak as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you are setting the listener.
You are setting the listener, then you rotate your device from landscape to portrait. What happens after the rotation is:

1. Android create a brand new instance of `MainActivity`.
2. `FragmentManager` create a new instance of `MyFragment` internally and re-adds it automatically to the activity as it was before orientation change.
3. If you click on the button, the listener will be called. However, the listener is the listener of the previous activity (before rotation) which has been destroyed.

So not only you have a Memory Leak (the old activity can not be garbage collected, because it's referenced from here) but you also get this error.

How to do it correctly:
Well, the problem is NOT only `setRetainInstanceState()` you have not understood the Android Fragments lifecycle correctly. As mentioned above, Fragments are controlled by the FragmentManager (FragmentTransaction). So, yes everytime you rotate your screen a new Fragment instance will be created, but FragmentManager will attach them automatically for you (it's a little bit strange, but thats how Fragment works)

I would recommend to use an `EventBus`. The fragment will fire an Event `onClick()` and the activity will receive this event since it's subscribed. I recomment [GreenDao EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).
Otherwise you can have a look at the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks), but from my point of view they are teaching not a good solution, because your fragment and activity are hardly connected (not modular). They say you should use `onAttach()` like you can see in the sample from the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks

Btw. a similar problem can occur if you are not using Fragment arguments for "passing"  data. For more details read this blog: http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/fragmentargs/

Comment: I effectively manage some AsyncTasks but I am sure they are stopped and released. I suspect FragmentManager to trying reuse the last fragment because it come from the same class as the new.

Comment: So are you sure that the AsyncTask is not accessing the fragments view components after the fragment is replaced by another?  Since there is a recursion, are you sure that Listener is not doing some ui things after the click event has triggered on the old Fragment?

Comment: Ah i see, the problem occures if you rotate the device (landscape to portrait or vice versa), right?

Comment: Not exactly, when I push the button only AFTER a configuration state change

Comment: May be it is in relationship with the `setRetainInstance(true)` statement?

Comment: Do you know how can I do?

Comment: I am sorry I can not up vote twice, thank you very much

Comment: If I can abuse of your competences, can you take a look here and give me a feedback if it is a good idea ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28080495/android-retain-objects-in-ui-fragment

Comment: @alex From my point of view non UI Fragments are bad practice ... You can solve this problem by using a good Software Architecture like Model-View-Presenter and `setReatinInstanceState(true)` but I have no time to explain it right now in more detail. Google for it

Comment: +1000 => "from my point of view they are teaching not a good solution, because your fragment and activity are hardly connected (not modular)"

Comment: Problem solved. I have to finish my project with non-ui fragment design pattern for timing reasons, but I'll find out about the model you recommended. If you fall on a good tutorial about it, think to me!