# android:configChanges with an Async SQLite Call in onCreate being called when orientation changes

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, android-configchanges

I am populating a ListView with the contents of an SQLite database. In my `onCreate` method in my `StartList` activity I call an `AsyncSQLite` which reads data from a JSON url and adds the data to the SQlite database.

But every time that I change my screen orientation, my app is calling the `AsyncSQLite` method again. I have added `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` to my `AndroidManifest.xml` but that doesn't seem to be making a difference.

Here is my `onCreate` method from my `StartList` activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_List);

    oslist.clear();
    oslist = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>();
    new AsyncSQLite().execute();
}
```

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".StartList"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_start_List"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

I thought that `onCreate` should only be called once when the activity is being created, but instead it is being called whenever I change the orientation.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128670/best-practice-asynctask-during-orientation-change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128670/best-practice-asynctask-during-orientation-change)

Comment: "I thought that onCreate should only be called once when the activity is being created" - This is a misconception, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: It work correctly, Try to clear you project. Don't use setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR); at your activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning the project fixed my issue.

Going to `Build`>`Clean Project`.