# AsyncTask & runtime config change: what approaches, with concise code samples, does the Android team endorse?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-lifecycle, android-memory, android-configchanges

Since [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) was introduced in Cupcake (API 3, Android 1.5) in 2009, it has been consistently promoted by the Android team as simple:

- "[Painless threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2009/05/painless-threading.html)"
- "[an easy way to execute some work in a background thread and publish the results back on the UI thread](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)".
- "[one of the simplest ways to fire off a new task from the UI thread](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)"

The code samples which they provide reinforce this message of simplicity, especially to those of us who have had to work with threads in [more painful ways](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html). `AsyncTask` is very attractive.

Yet in the many years since, crashes, memory leaks, and other problems have plagued most developers who have chosen to use `AsyncTask` in their production applications. This is often due to `Activity` [destruction and recreation on runtime configuration change](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) (especially orientation/rotation) while the `AsyncTask` is running [`doInBackground(Params...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) ; when [`onPostExecute(Result)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) is called, the `Activity` has already been destroyed, leaving UI references in an unusable state (or even `null`).

And the lack of obvious, clear, and concise guidance and code samples from the Android team on this issue has only made things worse, leading to confusion as well as various workarounds and hacks, some decent, some terrible:

- [Is AsyncTask really conceptually flawed or am I just missing something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357477/is-asynctask-really-conceptually-flawed-or-am-i-just-missing-something)
- [Best practice: AsyncTask during orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128670/best-practice-asynctask-during-orientation-change)
- [Lock orientation until Asynctask finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704774/lock-orientation-until-asynctask-finish)

Obviously, since `AsyncTask` can be used in many situations, there is no One Way to accommodate this issue.  My question, however, is about **options**.

What are the canonical (endorsed by the Android team) best practices, with concise code samples, for integrating `AsyncTask` with the `Activity`/`Fragment` lifecycle and automatic restarts on runtime configuration change?

Answer (score 11):

## Provided recommendation (for any approach)

### Don't hold references to UI-specific objects

From [Memory & Threading. (Android Performance Patterns Season 5, Ep. 3)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBHPmQQNiS8#t=2m11s):

> You've got some threading object that's declared as an inner class of an [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). The problem here is that the [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) object now has an implicit reference to the enclosing `Activity`, and will keep that reference until the work object has been destroyed... Until this work completes, the `Activity` stays around in memory... This type of pattern also leads to common types of crashes seen in Android apps...
>
> The takeaway here is that you shouldn't hold references to *any* types of UI-specific objects in *any* of your threading scenarios.

## Provided approaches

Although the documentation is sparse and scattered, the Android team have provided at least three distinct approaches to dealing with restarts on config change using `AsyncTask`:

1. Cancel/save/restart the running task in lifecycle methods
2. Use `WeakReference`s to UI objects
3. Manage in the top-level `Activity` or `Fragment` using "work records"

### 1. Cancel/save/restart the running task in lifecycle methods

From [Using AsyncTask | Processes and Threads | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#AsyncTask)

> To see how you can persist your task during one of these restarts and how to properly cancel the task when the activity is destroyed, see the source code for the [Shelves](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/) sample application.

In the Shelves app, references to the tasks are maintained as fields in an [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), so that they can be managed in the `Activity`'s lifecycle methods. Before taking a look at the code, however, there are a couple of important things to note.

First, this app was written before [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) was added to the platform.  A class that strongly resembles what was later released as `AsyncTask` is included in the source, called `UserTask`.  For our discussion here, `UserTask` is functionally equivalent to `AsyncTask`.

Second, subclasses of `UserTask` are declared as inner classes of an `Activity`. This approach is now regarded as an anti-pattern, as noted earlier (see *Don't hold references to UI specific objects* above). Fortunately, this implementation detail doesn't impact the overall approach of managing running tasks in lifecycle methods; however, if you choose to use this sample code for your own app, declare your subclasses of `AsyncTask` elsewhere.

#### Canceling the task

- Override [`onDestroy()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()), cancel the tasks, and set task references to `null`.  *(I'm not sure if setting references to `null` has any impact here; if you have further info, please comment and I'll update the answer accordingly).*
- Override [`AsyncTask#onCancelled(Object)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onCancelled%28Result%29) if you need to clean up or perform any other needed work after [`AsyncTask#doInBackground(Object[])`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) returns.

`AddBookActivity.java`

```
public class AddBookActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener,
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    // ...

    private SearchTask mSearchTask;
    private AddTask mAddTask;

    // Tasks are initialized and executed when needed
    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        onCancelAdd();
        onCancelSearch();
    }

    // ...

    private void onCancelSearch() {
        if (mSearchTask != null && mSearchTask.getStatus() == UserTask.Status.RUNNING) {
            mSearchTask.cancel(true);
            mSearchTask = null;
        }
    }

    private void onCancelAdd() {
        if (mAddTask != null && mAddTask.getStatus() == UserTask.Status.RUNNING) {
            mAddTask.cancel(true);
            mAddTask = null;
        }
    }

    // ...

    // DO NOT DECLARE YOUR TASK AS AN INNER CLASS OF AN ACTIVITY
    // Instances of this class will hold an implicit reference to the enclosing
    // Activity as long as the task is running, even if the Activity has been
    // otherwise destroyed by the system.  Declare your task where you can be
    // sure it holds no implicit references to UI-specific objects (Views,
    // etc.), and do not hold explicit references to them in your own
    // implementation.
    private class AddTask extends UserTask<String, Void, BooksStore.Book> {
        // ...

        @Override
        public void onCancelled() {
            enableSearchPanel();
            hidePanel(mAddPanel, false);
        }

        // ...
    }

    // DO NOT DECLARE YOUR TASK AS AN INNER CLASS OF AN ACTIVITY
    // Instances of this class will hold an implicit reference to the enclosing
    // Activity as long as the task is running, even if the Activity has been
    // otherwise destroyed by the system.  Declare your task where you can be
    // sure it holds no implicit references to UI-specific objects (Views,
    // etc.), and do not hold explicit references to them in your own
    // implementation.
    private class SearchTask extends UserTask<String, ResultBook, Void>
            implements BooksStore.BookSearchListener {

        // ...

        @Override
        public void onCancelled() {
            enableSearchPanel();

            hidePanel(mSearchPanel, true);
        }

        // ...
    }
```

#### Saving and restarting the task

- Override [`onSaveInstanceState(Bundle, PersistableBundle)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)), cancel the tasks, and save state about the tasks so they can be restarted when instance state is restored.
- Override [`onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle, PersistableBundle)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)), retrieve state about canceled tasks, and start new tasks with the data from the canceled task state.

`AddBookActivity.java`

```
public class AddBookActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener,
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    // ...

    private static final String STATE_ADD_IN_PROGRESS = "shelves.add.inprogress";
    private static final String STATE_ADD_BOOK = "shelves.add.book";

    private static final String STATE_SEARCH_IN_PROGRESS = "shelves.search.inprogress";
    private static final String STATE_SEARCH_QUERY = "shelves.search.book";

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        // ...
        restoreAddTask(savedInstanceState);
        restoreSearchTask(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (isFinishing()) {
            // ...
            saveAddTask(outState);
            saveSearchTask(outState);
        }
    }

    // ...

    private void saveAddTask(Bundle outState) {
        final AddTask task = mAddTask;
        if (task != null && task.getStatus() != UserTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            final String bookId = task.getBookId();
            task.cancel(true);

            if (bookId != null) {
                outState.putBoolean(STATE_ADD_IN_PROGRESS, true);
                outState.putString(STATE_ADD_BOOK, bookId);
            }

            mAddTask = null;
        }
    }

    private void restoreAddTask(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_ADD_IN_PROGRESS)) {
            final String id = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_ADD_BOOK);
            if (!BooksManager.bookExists(getContentResolver(), id)) {
                mAddTask = (AddTask) new AddTask().execute(id);
            }
        }
    }

    private void saveSearchTask(Bundle outState) {
        final SearchTask task = mSearchTask;
        if (task != null && task.getStatus() != UserTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            final String bookId = task.getQuery();
            task.cancel(true);

            if (bookId != null) {
                outState.putBoolean(STATE_SEARCH_IN_PROGRESS, true);
                outState.putString(STATE_SEARCH_QUERY, bookId);
            }

            mSearchTask = null;
        }
    }

    private void restoreSearchTask(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_SEARCH_IN_PROGRESS)) {
            final String query = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_SEARCH_QUERY);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) {
                mSearchTask = (SearchTask) new SearchTask().execute(query);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is a straightforward approach, and should make sense even to beginners who are just getting acquainted with the `Activity` lifecycle. It also has the advantage of not requiring mimimal code outside of the task class itself, touching one to three lifecycle methods, depending on needs. A simple, 7-line `onDestroy()` snippet in the Usage section of the `AsyncTask` [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) could have saved us all a lot of grief. Perhaps some future generation may be spared.

### 2. Use WeakReferences to UI objects

- Pass UI objects as parameters in the [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)'s constructor.  Store weak references to these objects as [`WeakReference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) fields in the `AsyncTask`.
- In [`onPostExecute()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)), check that the UI object `WeakReference`s are not `null` then update them directly.

From [Use an AsyncTask | Processing Bitmaps Off the UI Thread | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html#async-task)

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private int data = 0;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        data = params[0];
        return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), data, 100, 100));
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> The [`WeakReference`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to the [`ImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) ensures that the [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) does not prevent the [`ImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) and anything it references from being garbage collected. There’s no guarantee the [`ImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) is still around when the task finishes, so you must also check the reference in [`onPostExecute()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)). The [`ImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) may no longer exist, if for example, the user navigates away from the activity or if a configuration change happens before the task finishes.

This approach is simpler and tidier than the first, adding only a type change and a null check to the task class, and no additional code anywhere else.

There is a cost to this simplicity, however: the task will run to its end without being canceled on config change.  If your task is expensive (CPU, memory, battery), has side effects, or needs to be automatically restarted on [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) restart, then the first approach is probably a better option.

### 3. Manage in the top-level Activity or Fragment using "work records"

From [Memory & Threading. (Android Performance Patterns Season 5, Ep. 3)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBHPmQQNiS8#t=3m23s)

> ...force the top-level [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) or [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) to be the sole system responsible for updating the UI objects.
>
> For example, when you'd like to kick off some work, create a "work record" that pairs a [`View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) with some update function. When that block of work is finished, it submits the results back to the `Activity` using an [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) or a [`runOnUiThread(Runnable)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) call.
>
> The `Activity` can then call the update function with the new information, or if the `View` isn't there, just drop the work altogether. And, if the `Activity` that issued the work was destroyed, then the new `Activity` won't have a reference to any of this, and it will just drop the work, too.

Here is a screenshot of the accompanying diagram that describes this approach:

[image: Work Records thread management approach diagram]

Code samples were not provided in the video, so here is my take on a basic implementation:

#### `WorkRecord.java`

```
public class WorkRecord {
  public static final String ACTION_UPDATE_VIEW = "WorkRecord.ACTION_UPDATE_VIEW";
  public static final String EXTRA_WORK_RECORD_KEY = "WorkRecord.EXTRA_WORK_RECORD_KEY";
  public static final String EXTRA_RESULT = "WorkRecord.EXTRA_RESULT";
  public final int viewId;
  public final Callback callback;

  public WorkRecord(@IdRes int viewId, Callback callback) {
    this.viewId = viewId;
    this.callback = callback;
  }

  public interface Callback {
    boolean update(View view, Object result);
  }

  public interface Store {
    long addWorkRecord(WorkRecord workRecord);
  }
}
```

#### `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WorkRecord.Store {
  // ...

  private final Map<Long, WorkRecord> workRecords = new HashMap<>();
  private BroadcastReceiver workResultReceiver;

  // ...

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...

    initWorkResultReceiver();
    registerWorkResultReceiver();
  }

  @Override protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // ...

    unregisterWorkResultReceiver();
  }

  // Initializations

  private void initWorkResultReceiver() {
      workResultReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          doWorkWithResult(intent);
        }
      };
    }

  // Result receiver

  private void registerWorkResultReceiver() {
    final IntentFilter workResultFilter = new IntentFilter(WorkRecord.ACTION_UPDATE_VIEW);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(workResultReceiver, workResultFilter);
  }

  private void unregisterWorkResultReceiver() {
    if (workResultReceiver != null) {
      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(workResultReceiver);
    }
  }

  private void doWorkWithResult(Intent resultIntent) {
    final long key = resultIntent.getLongExtra(WorkRecord.EXTRA_WORK_RECORD_KEY, -1);
    if (key <= 0) {
      Log.w(TAG, "doWorkWithResult: WorkRecord key not found, exiting:"
          + " intent=" + resultIntent);
      return;
    }

    final Object result = resultIntent.getExtras().get(WorkRecord.EXTRA_RESULT);
    if (result == null) {
      Log.w(TAG, "doWorkWithResult: Result not found, exiting:"
          + " key=" + key
          + ", intent=" + resultIntent);
      return;
    }

    final WorkRecord workRecord = workRecords.get(key);
    if (workRecord == null) {
      Log.w(TAG, "doWorkWithResult: matching WorkRecord not found, exiting:"
          + " key=" + key
          + ", workRecords=" + workRecords
          + ", result=" + result);
      return;
    }

    final View viewToUpdate = findViewById(workRecord.viewId);
    if (viewToUpdate == null) {
      Log.w(TAG, "doWorkWithResult: viewToUpdate not found, exiting:"
          + " key=" + key
          + ", workRecord.viewId=" + workRecord.viewId
          + ", result=" + result);
      return;
    }

    final boolean updated = workRecord.callback.update(viewToUpdate, result);
    if (updated) workRecords.remove(key);
  }

  // WorkRecord.Store implementation

  @Override public long addWorkRecord(WorkRecord workRecord) {
    final long key = new Date().getTime();
    workRecords.put(key, workRecord);
    return key;
  }
}
```

#### `MyTask.java`

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Object> {
  // ...
  private final Context appContext;
  private final long workRecordKey;
  private final Object otherNeededValues;

  public MyTask(Context appContext, long workRecordKey, Object otherNeededValues) {
    this.appContext = appContext;
    this.workRecordKey = workRecordKey;
    this.otherNeededValues = otherNeededValues;
  }

  // ...

  @Override protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    final Intent resultIntent = new Intent(WorkRecord.ACTION_UPDATE_VIEW);
    resultIntent.putExtra(WorkRecord.EXTRA_WORK_RECORD_KEY, workRecordKey);
    resultIntent.putExtra(WorkRecord.EXTRA_RESULT, result);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(appContext).sendBroadcast(resultIntent);
  }
}
```

#### (the class where you initiate the task)

```
  // ...
  private WorkRecord.Store workRecordStore;
  private MyTask myTask;

  // ...

  private void initWorkRecordStore() {
    // TODO: get a reference to MainActivity and check instanceof WorkRecord.Store
    workRecordStore = (WorkRecord.Store) activity;
  }

  private void startMyTask() {
    final long key = workRecordStore.addWorkRecord(key, createWorkRecord());
    myTask = new MyTask(getApplicationContext(), key, otherNeededValues).execute()
  }

  private WorkRecord createWorkRecord() {
    return new WorkRecord(R.id.view_to_update, new WorkRecord.Callback() {
      @Override public void update(View view, Object result) {
        // TODO: update view using result
      }
    });
  }
```

Obviously, this approach is a huge effort compared to the other two, and overkill for many implementations. For larger apps that do a lot of threading work, however, this can serve as a suitable base architecture.

Implementing this approach exactly as described in the video, the task will run to its end without being canceled on config change, like the second approach above.  If your task is expensive (CPU, memory, battery), has side effects, or needs to be automatically restarted on `Activity` restart, then you would need to modify this approach to accommodate canceling, optionally saving and restarting, the task.  Or just stick with the first approach; Romain had a clear vision for this and implemented it well.

## Corrections

This is a big answer, and it's likely that I have made errors and omissions.  If you find any, please comment and I'll update the answer.  Thanks!