# Android TCP connection on changing orientation

Tags: android, tcp

I am trying to develop a simple chat application, only for study purpose. 
My problem is that when the screen orientation is changing the TCP/IP connection is closed and recreated after orientation changes.

I know that Android destroys the activity and recreates it when changing orientation.

So my question: It is posible to change only view but everything else to remain intact?

Thanks

Comment: Possibility: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584015/handle-screen-orientation-changes-when-there-are-asynctasks-running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the real issue here is that you are performing the TCP/IP connection on the main UI thread, which is a terrible idea because you risk blocking touch events and the layouts from being generated. A `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is thrown on most new devices these days to prevent this behavior too.

What I would do is wrap the TCP/IP connection in a `Thread`, and then have the `Thread` execute in a worker (non-UI, invisible) `Fragment` with `setRetainInstance(true)`. This protect your `Thread` on configuration changes, as the `Fragment` will remain in memory even when the `Activity` is destroyed. You can read more about this approach [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html).

If the TCP/IP connection needs to exist across multiple `Activity` instances, you should use a `Service` instead.

Comment: I would advise not using a AsyncTask for the TCP Connection, what if the user wishes to use the AsyncTask for other purposes?

Comment: @KarlMorrison AsyncTasks should be used for short tasks (3-4 seconds). If the TCP connection needs to persist over a long period of time, then it would be better to use a service. I'm not sure what you mean by "what if the user wishes to use `AsyncTask` for other purposes.

Comment: I think what @Karl Morrison is referring to is the pool limit for async tasks. In newer android versions they are essentially serially executed unless you specify parallel execution. On older versions you never know, usually you can run two in parallel. As you mentioned it's ok to run a short task like this even if using TCP connection in them but if you want to create something like a chat or sending game moves you should really create a service with a worker thread.

Comment: @PSIXO I've edited my answer assuming the TCP connection will last longer than a few seconds. `AsyncTask`s are good for short-lived async computations, but if you need to persist a TCP connection for longer than that, it is better to use a retained `Fragment` or a `Service`.

Answer (score 3):

You should implement your TCP/IP communications as [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and then it will not depend on any orientation change/other recreating of your activity.

Answer (score 2):

You want to read the section called **Handling the Configuration Change Yourself** in the [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) document. In short, you tell it you will handle them manually by adding `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` to your Activity decleration in your AndroidManifest. Here is an example:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

And then in your Activity you override `onConfigurationChanged` like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK... but what if the user puts the phone in a dock? Or what if the user changes the locale? This will cause the `Activity` to be destroyed/recreated just the same. Now what?

Answer (score 1):

You can either make your connection static and not recreate it when it is != null, or even better you wrap it into a separate class that uses the singleton pattern

Comment: why would it do that? just the tcp connection has to be static and is therefore created just once.

Comment: that is why you use the application context and not the activity itself whenever possible...

Comment: this was a general comment. it is clear to me to use the application context for database connections for example so no activities can leak. but i anyways do not see why a activity would leak in this case, because no context is required to open a socket connection: sSocket = new Socket(hostAddr, servPort);

Comment: I like the application context as a holder for objects but keep in mind that you might not be using the TCP connection instance during the whole life of your application. Service would definitely be a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't create the connection from the activity.
You can use Application instead:

in your manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication" ...>
```

It will be created once, and live throughout the whole life of your application, even when activities are destroyed.

Other alternative is a Service. For a chat application I would use that, since it seperates the background network work from the UI completely.

Comment: Just a little caution: In some testing I'm doing on a current application, I'm finding that the `Application` instance is often killed (and soon after created again) even when the `Activity` stack remains. This is of course when the phone is left for a long period with the `Activity` stack in the background. Therefore the point I'd make from my experiences is that `Activity` classes should always check that "global" references you've stored in `Application` are still actually there, and be prepared to create them again if not.

Comment: What you describe should never happen.
When an Application is killed (which often happens), the activities belonging to it *must* be killed too by the system. Did you look for memory leaks in your app, keeping zombie activities around?

Comment: Agreed - it was unexpected. This occurs on my HTC One X, which on XDADevs is known for running low on memory, sometimes even killing the launcher. My app's `Application` is typically recreated when the phone is left for an hour or overnight with activity stack in background. On resuming, the topmost `Activity` resumes, but `Application` is new instance. I have a `Toast` that tells me when `Application` has been re-initialised, and I occasionally see the system kill and then recreate the `Application` for my app in the background, while I'm doing something else (e.g. web browsing). [TBC]

Comment: In terms of memory leaks, I *think* it's okay. I have extensively tested by rotating orientation, and discovered and eliminated leaks this way. The `Application` class holds a lot of "singleton" data. Now, on resuming, all my `Activity` classes *must* check `Application` "global" structures exist, and trigger their recreation if not. In fact I notice a few apps (not my own) that appear to lose state when their stack is resumed on my HTC One X, if some time passed since their last use (DI FM Radio app being an example). I ought to create a separate Stackoverflow question for this I think.

Comment: Wow, that looks like a major flaw in HTC One X, I wonder how they've passed CTS (if there are tests covering this scenario). Google should have been more strict about approving ports.