# When i rotate the device (Android), the adapter variable receives null?

Tags: android, rotation, save, instance, adapter

In the code below (shortened for clarity) when I rotate the device, the adapter variable receives null and gridView variable receives null.

Can anyone help me keep the adapter and gridView after rotating the device screen?

Thank.

(Sorry for bad english)

```
    public class FlickrXmlFragment extends Fragment {

    private GridView gridView;
    private FlickrGridViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //...
        View view = darkInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_flickr_xml,
                container, false);
        //...
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.flickr_gridView);

        return view;
    }

    class FlickrPhotoSearchThread extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, List<FlickrImagem>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() { //... process...    }

        @Override
        protected List<FlickrImagem> doInBackground(String... params) { //process... }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<FlickrImagem> result) {
            //...
            adapter = new FlickrGridViewAdapter(getActivity(), 0, result);
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fetch those values in `onResume` again and use it, since activity restarts on rotation, which means your data may be lost

Comment: you might take a look at this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584015/handle-screen-orientation-changes-when-there-are-asynctasks-running

Answer (score -1):

Handle the Orientation changes for your activity.

Please refer to this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

Declare your activity like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: Thank you! I had only just declared android:configChanges="orientation" and was not working

Comment: You should probably save the state and then restore it, this method makes it so the activity doesn't restart. See [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#saras).